# How to gracefully terminate a remote service process?

Tags: android, service

Currently I believe I'm doing a ok job managing my applications remote service.  When I'm done using it I can see the onDestroy() called, perfect...

Now the issue is I can see the remote process still hanging, via DDMS or via phone's running processes.  Users see this and think I'm doing stuff on the background etc... blaming my app and than asking for an exit button... Truth is they don't need an exit button!

So my question:

> How to gracefully terminate a remote
>   service process?

I could get the PID and kill it but something tells me this might not be the nice way to do this since the service might be restarted again...

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

-Jona

Comment: Give them an Exit button. Make it a non-op. Then tell them it's Android's fault that it didn't exit when they pressed the button. :)

Comment: lol... Yeah, but I'm all about getting things working just right. All I need to do is remove the process, I'm shutting down the service just fine but I need it to go away too... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Currently I believe I'm doing a ok job managing my applications remote service.

Simple solution: get rid of the remote service. If you wrote the app and the service, then you do not need it to be remote. The only time you need it to be remote is if the app and the service are part of two separate apps.

> Now the issue is I can see the remote process still hanging, via DDMS or via phone's running processes.

Of course.

> How to gracefully terminate a remote service process?

You don't. Android will terminate it if and when it chooses to. Hence, the simple solution is to get rid of the remote service process by not having a remote service in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well currently my application is an online streaming application. Please correct me if I'm wrong, which I might be. One process in Android is assigned an amount of memory and CPU. By having a process for streaming media and the other process for the UI, I believe the application would feel snapier. Your idea to make it all run on one process sounds good but not sure about the process life cycle... Would it be affected in any way? I guess I could read more about that... :P

Comment: @Moto: "By having a process for streaming media and the other process for the UI, I believe the application would feel snapier." -- on existing hardware, that is doubtful. With multi-core devices, it is a bit more likely, but I still think background threads will be more than sufficient. "Would it be affected in any way?" -- I do not understand the question, sorry.

Comment: I ment if the lifecycle of the service be affected in any way if it is running within the same process of an activity.

Comment: @Moto: It is not. The lifecycle remains the same.